# Would just sending a custom header to my REST API be enough to protect my site against CSRF?

Tags: ajax, csrf

ASP.Net MVC has a feature called AntiForgeryToken, which create a hidden field and a cookie, and when the submit is done, the values must match in order to proceed the request. I have a set of APIs, and my posts to my APIs are always through XMLHttpRequest, and CORS is disabled. Is creating a header with constant value enough to protect against CSRF?

Just to clarify: I will have an authorization token, but this is will be in a cookie (which is a header, of course, but I don’t need to set this header; the browser does it automatically), and my API will run over SSL.

But why must my header destinated to antiforgery needs to have some token? Why not just a constant value, just to check if the header is there? If someone create its own page button to make a post to my API, it will not set the header with the constant value, so I will refuse to process the request. If someone create its own page to make an XMLHttpRequest, setting the header value, then the browser will not comply the post, because I've disabled CORS. So, do I need a token in the header? Just a constant value to header just to be there would not be enough?